# Arabic_CI_AS to utf8 in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, utf-8

I have a DataBase in **Sql Server** with collection **Arabic_CI_AS** and i need to compare some string data with another **Postgres** Database with **Utf8** character set. Also i use C# for convert & compare. It easy done when string contains just one word (in these cases i should just replace 'ي' to 'ی'), but for long string special with **'('** charachter  has problem.

I cant do it! I try some suggested solution such as:

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
byte[] encBytes = enc.GetBytes(customer.name);
customer.name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encBytes, 0, encBytes.Length);
```

or:

```
SELECT cast (name as nvarchar) as NewName 
from Customer
```

But they dont work! Can anyone help me?

---

Example of input and output, see tooltips on the right:

[image: My input & out put is like this]

Comment: "They don't work" is too vague so it is not possible to help you. Could you give exact samples of input and output ([edit] the question).

Comment: input: (نماينده اراک) آقاي قاسمي output: (??????? ????) ???? ?????

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you to change your collation dynamically

```
SELECT name  collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
from Customer
```

or

```
SELECT name  collate Persian_100_CI_AI
    from Customer
```

or 
you can try this in c# side

```
string _Value=string.Empty;
byte[] enBuff= Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256").GetBytes(customer.name);
customer.name= Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetString(enBuff);
```

you can choose another collations too.
you should change many collation and Encoding number to get wanted result.

Comment: Thanks, but this makes string worse, all character change to '?' character

Comment: I try all of them, last result is: (äãÇíäÏå ÇÑÇ˜) ÂÞÇí ÞÇÓãí

Comment: @zahrakhoobi – If you check them in hexadecimal editor (let's check only text in parentheses `(نماينده اراک)`), they should be like: 28  which is `(` and then D9 86 D9 85 D8 A7 D9 8A D9 86 D8 AF etc.   Could you verify your output in hexadecimal form? This eliminates possible display issues on interpreting the output.

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari -  hex number for string (نماینده اراک) is: 28 e4 e3 c7 ed e4 cf e5 20 c7 d1 c7 98 29

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support `utf-8` strings. If you have to deal with characters other than *plain-latin* it is strongly recommended to use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` with an arabic collation.

Many people think, that `NVARCHAR` is `utf-16` while `VARCHAR` is `utf-8`. This is not true! The second is *extended ASCII* and is using 1 byte in any case, while `utf-8` will encode some characters with more than one byte.

So - the most important question is: WHY?

SQL Server can take your string into a `NVARCHAR` variable, cast it to a *chain of bytes* and re-cast it to the former string:

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'(نماینده اراک)';

SELECT @str
      ,CAST(@str AS VARBINARY(MAX))
      ,CAST(CAST(@str AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

The problem with the `)` is - quite probably! - that your arabic letters are *right-to-left* while the `)` is *left-to-right*. I wanted to paste the result of the query above into this answer but did not manage to get the closing `)` to the original place... You try to edit, delete, replace, but you get something else... Somehow funny, but not a question of bad encoding but one of buggy editors...

Anyway, SQL-Server is not your issue. You must read the string as `NVARCHAR` out of SQL-Server. C# is working with unicode strings and not a collated 1-byte string. Every conversion carries the chance to destroy your text.

If your target (or the tooltip you show us) is not capable to show the string properly, it might be perfectly okay, but the editor is not...

If you pass such an UTF-8 string back to SQL-Server, you'll get a mess...

The only place, where UTF-8 makes sense is written to a file or transmitted via small band. If a text contains very many plain latin characters and just a few strange letters (like ver often XML, HTML) you can save quite some diskspace or band with. With a far-east text you'd even bloat you text. Some of these characters will need 3 or even 4 bytes to be encoded.

Within your database and application you should stick with unicode.